# What is the most efficient way to set setState() to just refresh a page

Tags: dart, flutter

I need a help figuring out how to make a button that call on function let say function called _refresh() and it will just refresh the page.

I try to find an example online but it all for more complex functionality. Can someone help me? thank you!

Comment: Just refresh the page smells. Please elaborate on the concrete use case.

Comment: Okay let say i have a listbuilder in a page...i want to create a button that will simply refresh the page so the new list item will appear if any.

Comment: Adding the new item inside `setState(...)` should be enough. No need to refresh the whole page.